# WIX: Sort Function on Repeater Works in Preview but not Live Site

Tags: velo

I have a repeater that is connected to a dataset. The dataset is told to sort by a numerical ranking (high to low). When I preview, it works great. When I go live, I can see that it loads correctly, and then reverts to sorting by date (newest to oldest). Any idea why the Sort Function is getting overwritten?

```js
import wixData from 'wix-data';

const collectionName = 'Projects';
const fieldToFilterByInCollection = 'tags';

$w.onReady(function () {

    setRepeatedItemsInRepeater(100);
    loadDataToRepeater(100);

    $w('#selectionTags1').onChange((event) => {
        const selectedTags = $w('#selectionTags1').value;
        loadDataToRepeater(selectedTags);
        
    })

});

function loadDataToRepeater(selectedCategories = []) {

    let dataQuery = wixData.query(collectionName);

    if (selectedCategories.length > 0) {
        dataQuery = dataQuery.hasSome(fieldToFilterByInCollection, selectedCategories);
    }

    dataQuery
        .find()
        .then(results => {
            const itemsReadyForRepeater = results.items;
            $w('#repeater1').data = itemsReadyForRepeater;
            const isRepeaterEmpty = itemsReadyForRepeater.length === 0

            if (isRepeaterEmpty) {
                $w('#container1').show();
            } else {
                $w('#container1').show();
            }
        })
}

function setRepeatedItemsInRepeater() {

    $w('#repeater1').onItemReady(($item, itemData) => {
        $item('#container1').src = itemData.projectimage;
        $item('#container1').tooltip = itemData.projectimage;

    })
}
```

Comment: do you have any code which runs on page ready? a filter code perhaps?

Comment: I have a query to change the results based on which selector tags are chosen. 
Could this be affecting my Sort Order? I added my code above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Wix Data Query function [overrides the sort parameter](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-data/query) and resets it to sort descending by created data. When you are building the Query before you find, use the [descending function](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-data/wixdataquery/descending) or [ascending function](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-data/wixdataquery/ascending) to keep it set to your desired field.

```js
wixData.query("collectionName").descending("fieldName").find()
```